# C# signalr multi-process issue

Tags: asp.net

Multiple processes are used in the IIS application pool.

The system operates normally in the application pool where signalr communication has the same ID value.

However, when refreshing or accessing a new
When the process ID is assigned to another place, there is a problem that communication is not possible.

---

backend code:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
}
```

frontend code:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "@(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))/signalr/hubs";

var connection = 
$.hubConnection("@(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))/signalr/hubs");

chat = connection.createHubProxy('chat');

connection.start().done(function () {

chat.invoke('JoinRoom', "room_@Model.Index");
});
```

---

Considering that there is no problem when communicating in processes with the same ID value
I don't think it's a code error. Is there a similar solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: found that the behavior is not allowed by the cors and signalr policies.
The solution to this was solved by adding a sub-server in charge of socket communication only and interlocking it.